# Remove all trailing zeroes in Python list

Tags: python, list

Is there a faster way to remove zeros than this:

```
while L[-1] == 0:
    L.pop(-1)
```

Any prebuilt functions or anything similar?

Comment: No, there's no built-in function for this.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Is this really a duplicate? The question is if there is a faster way than the provided code. The question you have pointed to has nothing useful to answer this question.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate either. I had already seen that question during my searches anyway.

Comment: map(lambda _: _ if _ else "", L)

Comment: @chapelo That doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @user230373 Have you tried timing any of those solutions then? How do you know whether this is fast or slow? If yes, include them in the question.

Comment: ''.join(L).rstrip('0')

Comment: @chapelo: please don't provide answers as comments.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, do you want to remove all instances of 0 from the end of your list? Are you trying to remove trailing 0s from all integers in a list?

Comment: Aside: this code, as written, throws an exception if the list is all `0`s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Three possible micro optimizations:

**1. Use `del my_list[index]` instead of `mylist.pop(index)` when you want to *just* delete an item by its index.**

Its slightly faster:

```
import dis
def del_by_pop(mylist):
    mylist.pop(-1)

def del_by_del(mylist):
    del mylist[-1]
```

Using the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/dis.html) we can look at what's happening underneath.

`dis.dis(del_by_pop)` prints the following:

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (mylist)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (pop)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (-1)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 POP_TOP
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

`dis.dis(del_by_del)` prints the following:

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (mylist)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (-1)
              6 DELETE_SUBSCR
              7 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

`del` has less work to do because it doesn't need to return the popped item.

**2. use a for loop instead of a while loop.**

```
def del_for(mylist):
    for i in reversed(mylist):
        if not i:
            del mylist[-1]
        else:
            break
```

**3. don't use `del` at all, just slice the list once you've found the position of the last non-zero item**

```
def del_for(mylist):
    for i, j in enumerate(reversed(mylist)):
        if j:
            mylist = mylist[:-1*i]
            break
```

Comment: I think option 3 will fail for lists that do not have any trailing zeros (e.g. mylist = [0, 100]). It will attempt to set mylist = mylist[:-0] which returns []

Answer (score 2):

use `del` and delete just once:

```
# rstrip_list.py

def rstrip(L, hit):
    while L[-1] == hit:
        L.pop(-1)

def fast_rstrip(L, hit):
    for i in xrange(len(L) - 1, -1, -1):
        if L[i] != hit:
            break
    del L[i + 1:]

import cProfile

L1 = range(1, 1000000) + [0] * 10000
L2 = range(1, 1000000) + [0] * 10000

cProfile.run('rstrip(L1, 0)')
cProfile.run('fast_rstrip(L2, 0)')
```

and the result:

```
$ python rstrip_list.py

         10003 function calls in 0.004 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.004 <string>:1(<module>)
    1    0.003    0.003    0.004    0.004 rstrip_list.py:5(rstrip)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    10000    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}


         4 function calls in 0.001 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.001    0.001 rstrip_list.py:10(fast_rstrip)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```